# Построение автообновляемого не стандартного графика (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, графики

Имеется Arduino с подключенным к ней датчиком, она непрерывно посылает по `serial` порту данные в виде `b'000'\r\n`.

Есть функция, которая в бесконечном цикле отлавливает данные значения, переводит в `str`, избавляется от лишних символов, оставляя только трехзначное значимое число, а так же пишет эти числа в список и файл по 100 значений (или 50, или 25 - это не принципиально), после чего очищает список, а в файле переходит на новую строку.

---

Требуется провести цветовое кодирование полученных данных и вывести каким либо способом, т.е. подставить каждому значению в соответствие цвет:

0,35-0,49с – фиолетовый - n 7,
0,5-0,57с – красный- n 6,
0,58-0,64с – серый - n 5,
0,65-0,79с – синий - n 4,
0,8-0,94с –зеленый - n 3,
0,95-1,09с - желтый - n 2,
свыше 1,1с – белый –n 1,

— и вывести на экран соответствующий график.

---

***Мой код:***

```py
def readFromArd(): ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200):
    fileIBI = open('IBI.txt', 'w')
    fileIBI.close()

    valueListIBI = []

    while True :

        listIndex = 0

        while (listIndex != 50):

            valueIBI = str( ser.readline() )
            lenLine = len(valueIBI)
            valueListIBI.append(valueIBI[2:(lenLine-5)])

            with open('IBI.txt', 'a') as fileIBI:
                fileIBI.write( str(valueListIBI[listIndex]) )
                fileIBI.write(' ')

            listIndex += 1

            if listIndex == 50:
                with open('IBI.txt', 'a') as fileIBI:
                    fileIBI.write('\n')
        else:
            drawGraph1(valueListIBI)
            valueListIBI.clear()
```

---

Это может быть как просто "забор" из раскрашенных прямоугольников одинакового размера, которые будут соответствовать данным, либо, например, гистограмма. Главное, чтобы наглядно было видно изменение значений по цветам.

Реализацию "забора" вообще не смог нигде найти. Гистограмму позволяет строить `matplotlib`, но как заставить его отрисовывать каждый столбец разным цветом, да и еще динамически обновлять по мере поступления новых данных (новых 100, 50 или 25 значений), так и не понял.

Так же требуется данный график встроить в интерфейс на `tkinter`, что так же не понятно , как делать.

---

Нужно максимально простейшее и понятное решение. Если есть у кого-нибудь мысли, советы - с радостью выслушаю. Win/Python 3.7/PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то вам надо, на сколько я понял, использовать построение bar-графиков. А в функции barplot библиотеки matplotlib есть параметр color который на вход принимает вектор значений цветов отдельных столбцов.

Глянуть можно, например, вот тут:

https://towardsdatascience.com/a-step-by-step-guide-for-creating-advanced-python-data-visualizations-with-seaborn-matplotlib-1579d6a1a7d0

и тут:

https://python-graph-gallery.com/3-control-color-of-barplots/

А вот тут можете глянуть разные варианты отрисовки динамических графиков и подобрать тот, который вам наиболее подойдет:

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/05/animations-with-matplotlib.html

Кстати, посмотрите, может библиотека plotly вам для целей графического отображения подойдет (понравиться) больше:

https://tproger.ru/translations/python-data-vizualization/

Ну и про рисование в рамках tkinter:

https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/

Comment: Большое спасибо, ознакомлюсь. Вот как раз про вектор значений нигде не видел, чтобы было написано, скорее всего это мне и подойдет.

Comment: Поскольку вы новый участник SO подсказываю, что благодарность тут принято высказывать, отметив ответ как полезный. За одно - добавлю еще про цвета на графике, раз для вас это новинка https://jenyay.net/Matplotlib/Colors. Могу также рекомендовать http://geometry.karazin.ua/resources/documents/20161211134615_988a1d6a.pdf как очень хорошее описание всего, что может понадобиться в начале работы с Python.